# function toISOstring returns one day previous value

Tags: javascript, date-fns

My JSON has an exctraction date `2023-06-16T00:00:00`And what I need is to show it in a list with this format: `dd/MM/yyyy`

For that, I'm using this method:

```
const formatDate = (
  date: any,
  ignoreHours: boolean = false,
  formatDate: string = "dd/MM/yyyy"
) => {
  if (!date || date === "") return;
  if (ignoreHours) date = new Date(date).toISOString().split("T")[0];
  const reg = /^\d+$/;
  const numbersOnlytest = reg.test(date);
  if (numbersOnlytest) {
    date = new Date(date).toISOString();
  }
  return format(parseISO(date), formatDate);
};
```

But the returned value is `15/06/2023`.

For what I search, I need to use `toISOString()` but this is not working.

Comment: Did you hear about time zones?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging I discover that the error was in ignore hours:

```
const formatDate = (
  date: any,
  ignoreHours: boolean = false,
  formatDate: string = "dd/MM/yyyy"
)
```

I only needed to switch the boolean value to `true`